# Typescript not doing case analysis correctly

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Say we want to define a function that takes in another function and its parameter, and outputs the function called with the parameter. This is a very good example where we'd want typescript to do proper case analysis. See below.

```
let fns = {
  A: (x: string) => 'a' + x,
  B: (y: number) => 100 + y
}

type fn = typeof fns[keyof typeof fns]

const combine = <T extends fn>(fn: T, param: Parameters<T>[0]) => {
  return fn(param)
}
```

The problem is that typescript is giving me the following error on the word param (on the line with the word return):
`Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2345)`

For some reason it's combining both types of input into one type, instead of understanding that `T` will only be one or the other. Help!

Comment: Will it help you understand why it combines them both when I point out that it's possible for a user to call it like this: `combine<fn>(fns.A, 0)`? If TypeScript did not raise an error here then this call would be valid, but result in undesirable behavior at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

(Using A and B to refer to the signatures separately)

TypeScript is actually correct here because `T extends fn` does **not** mean that `T` can only be "A" or "B". `T extends fn` is a constraint that means `T` must be assignable to `fn`. Sure, "A" and "B" are assignable to `fn`, but the type `A | B` is *also* assignable to `fn`.

That means someone could call your function like this:

```
combine<fn>(fns.A, 0);
```

If TypeScript were to allow this, then this call would be valid! This would result in unexpected and undesirable behavior. But don't fret, I've got two possible workarounds, each with their pros and cons.

---

One is to use an external signature and write the internal signature like this:

```
function combine<T extends fn>(fn: T, param: Parameters<T>[0]): ReturnType<T>;
function combine<T extends (x: unknown) => R, R>(fn: T, param: Parameters<T>[0]): R {
  return fn(param);
}
```

It's a bit ugly and unsafe but it does work while retaining the original signature. However, like I mentioned above, people *can* call it with the type `fn` instead of "A" or "B".

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WJ5M6m)

---

Similar to the first, this one uses individual overloads instead. It's *slightly* better than the first because it prevents users from calling it with unions of functions, but it's a lot more to type.

```
function combine(fn: typeof fns.A, param: string): string;
function combine(fn: typeof fns.B, param: number): number;
function combine<T extends (x: unknown) => R, R>(fn: T, param: Parameters<T>[0]): R {
  return fn(param)
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w23MYN)

There's probably better solutions, but I haven't had my morning coffee yet. Hopefully you at least understand why it's an error, but I'll still edit the answer with better solutions when I think of them.

Comment: I truly still don't understand. What would a value with type `A | B` look like?! (I guess I should look at typescript Function page more, but this seems dumb to me to union functions in an unintuitive way...) And thanks a lot for your detailed answer. I too will look at this more later.